# Create Number Counter that Counts Every 5th Number

Tags: vba, ms-access, counter

I have a textbox labeled, "Lot Number" in a form called, "Receiving Inspection Form". My users have to enter a lot number from material that has been received by our company. I want every 5th lot number to be checked by the inspector. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Lot_Number_AfterUpdate()

    Dim x As Integer

    x = 0

    If EndsWith(x) Then
    MsgBox "MUST PERFORM SPECTROMETER TEST!!!!!"
    Me.Lot_Number.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Research modulo division

Comment: @KevinDTimm shouldn't that be posted as an answer?  Ya know, for statistics and such?

Comment: @Newd - if I post as a comment I can help the OP and only give this amount of information.  If I make it an answer I feel that this brevity is not rewarded :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Which is what I figured, so then shouldn't this also become flagged as off topic because it has become trivial?

Comment: @KevinDTimm Guess it is moot at this point...

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere on the network if someone cares to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - and address the user politely:

```
Private Sub Lot_Number_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Lot As Integer
    Dim Sec As Integer

    Sec = Second(Time) \ 2    
    Lot = Val(Right(Nz(Me!Lot_Number.Value), 1))
    If Lot Mod 5 = Sec Then
        MsgBox "Please perform spectrometer test.", vbInformation + vbOkOnly, "Inspector Check"
        Me!Lot_Number.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Gustav, that is great....thank you! Do you, by chance know how I could add to this code to include a number ending in zero as well? Please advise.

Comment: You could study the recent edit. I changes - every time the function is called - the digit to compare, based on the last digit of the seconds of the actual time. This will not give an exact count of every fifth to be called for testing, but on a larger quantity it should do on the average.